# Reset Combo-box C# WP 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

my problem is that i don't know how to reset a combo-box to it's default value `choose an item`, after clicking a button. 
I only found the following code, but it erases all the items of tha combo-box which is not what i want!

> myCombo1.Items.Clear();

Also, is it possible to create an instance of `MainPage` and use it in navigation function?

> Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
myCombo1.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Comment: If this answers your question please mark it like so, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use simplly *clear()* method :
`ComboBoxName.Clear();`.

Comment: Hi Amira, i got this error message :Error 1 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ComboBox' does not contain a definition for 'Clear' and no extension method 'Clear' accepting a first argument of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ComboBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) What should i do ?